# How do I get a model instance associated with a listview row using setTag(int, object)?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview itemClickListener that should get the model instance associated with the row clicked.

I read about tags in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object)

I know that listview recycles rows, so it would not be a good idea to use v.setTag(currentItem), because that would result in an earlier row being associated with a later item.

So to solve my original problem, it looks like I need to use setTag(int, object) where the body of my click handler needs to know the unique key.  The documentation states to use a resource id value, but that is not unique amongst multiple rows.  How do I get the model instance for the row I clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to grab the item out of your adapter like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    ListAdapter a = (ListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
    Object itemAtPosition = a.getItem(position);
}
```